# Are there any JQuery slider controls available like this one?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I wanted to use the slider control like the one which is used on [inveni.com](http://www.inveni.com/).(click on  'rate' button for any movie and the control will appear.

I googled 'jQuery slider' and found only image sliders. Are there any jQuery slider plugins available like the one i mentioned above?

I tried to upload the image of that controller but my reputation is too low to upload it.
You can login to that site by using facebook connect.

Color of the slider changes in it when you hover on it and you don't even have to click on in order to make changes.

Comment: I supose you need to be logged in to see it.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the slider?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without being able to see the type of slider you mentioned I can only guess. Have you tried the Slider from jquery ui?

http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to give you the link. and I've seen the jQuery UI slider, it is good but I need something different.